# return iframe src value in alertbox while it getting attempt to load using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**but it return empty alert box.. pls anyone help me.**
I need alertbox with detail of iframe src(address location, http://www.google.com) value.

```
<iframe width="700px" height="900px" name="ifrm" id="ifrm" onload="load()"></iframe> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
var oIframe = document.getElementById("ifrm");

var oDoc = oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument;

if (oDoc.document) {

    oDoc = oDoc.document;
}
alert(oDoc.ifrm.href);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the src attribute of the iframe

```
alert(oDoc.ifrm.src);
```

Comment: It giving the following error. [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined]